# populating a column based on data in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a a df that looks like this:

```
VenNum, FiscalPeriod, Bool1, Bool2, Bool3
   001,      1      , False, False, False
   002,      3,     , False, False, False
```

I have a contract_df that looks like this

```
Num, CC   , 1   , 2    , 3
001, Bool1, True, False, False
001, Bool2, True, False, False
001, Bool3, True, False, False
002, Bool1, False,False, True
002, Bool2, False,False, True
002, Bool3, False,False, True
```

Ideally I would like to take the VenNum from DF and match it to the num in contract_df for each bool. I would then like to change the respective bool column in df by finding the column in df_contract that matches to fiscalperiod so that the result would be below

```
   VenNum, FiscalPeriod, Bool1, Bool2, Bool3
   001,      1         , True , True , True
   002,      3,        , True , True , True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pipeline. In summary, this is mostly reshaping to be able to `merge`:

```
(df1.drop(df1.filter(like='Bool').columns, axis=1)
    .merge(df2.set_index(['Num', 'CC'])
              .rename_axis('FiscalPeriod', axis=1)
              .stack().unstack('CC').reset_index()
              .astype({'FiscalPeriod': int})
              .rename(columns={'Num': 'VenNum'}),
           on=['VenNum', 'FiscalPeriod'],
           )
)
```

output:

```
   VenNum  FiscalPeriod  Bool1  Bool2  Bool3
0       1             1   True   True   True
1       2             3   True   True   True
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". Was wondering if you had any advice?